# Jquery Google Map Places - Getting Select Option

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:  http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/5dqHg/29/

It was working, to grab the country value and use it as the filter for the places autosuggest. However, I changed it to use a select box instead of an input, and it no longer works.

This is the bit of code I added:

```
var ctryiso = $( "#country option:selected" ).text();
```

Is there anything wrong with this, can anyone see why my script now no longer works? I don't get anything in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the value of the *select* not the text inside *option*

```
var ctryiso = $( "#country" ).val();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5dqHg/32/

---

If you have for example the following HTML

```
<select name="country" id="country">
  <option value="uk" selected>United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="us">United States</option>
</select>
```

then

```
var ctryiso = $( "#country option:selected" ).text();
```

would return *United Kingdom* but what you want is the **value** which here is *uk*

`<select>` will always take the value of the selected option so you don't have to use *option* as your selector

Comment: thank you for the answer, that works. Any idea why it doesn't update the autosuggest options when I change the country to United States though? Do I need to refresh the variable or something?

Comment: Yes, you need to recall the function again

Comment: I'm not sure how I do that, would you mind showing me please?

Comment: Not sure if this is the optimal way, but here you go http://jsfiddle.net/5dqHg/35/